# Fade buttons and labels in objective c for iPhone

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, fade, alpha

Hi I want to implement a general fade and reveal algorithm for a mix of UIButtons and UILabels for iPhone. I set the method to receive the object as id.
But I don't know how to get and set the alpha values for id objects.

I first tried myObject.alpha and then tried `[myObject getAlpha]` but Xcode says `getAlpha` method is not found. Anyone knows how to get the alpha value of an id object or recommend another way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you try passing a "UIView" object instead of an "id". If you want to set alpha values, then they must be UI elements, and UIView has an "alpha" property.

Comment: And yeah, you might want to start reading some beginner material. :)

Comment: Yes, I use the UIView with core animation and it worked like a charm, thanks. I guess I was too brief with my question so many people didn't know what I was talking about. Sorry for you to take the trouble to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try core Animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
[YOUR_OBJECT setAlpha:1.0f]; //or 0.0f
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

thanks.

Comment: Will try this too so as not mess with NSTimer an

Comment: This worked out great! Thanks. The codes are a lot cleaner now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would benefit from reading some beginner guides on the syntax required to get up and running, if you have experience with other languages you be able to skim the material pretty quickly.

It's a convention to name getter methods without the get word. So what you want is

```
[myObject alpha];
```

Now as you know that anything you want to fade is a subclass of `UIView` use `UIView` instead of `id`.

As `UILabel` and `UIButton` are both subclasses of `UIView` this would be fine

---

**Update**

With regards to @mohacs solution the Apple docs for [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW111) state

> `+ (void)beginAnimations:(NSString *)animationID context:(void *)context`
>
> Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You should use the block-based animation methods to specify your animations instead.

Therefore the block alternative would be

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                  animations:^{
                      [view setAlpha:alpha];
                  }];
```

Comment: The question even doesn't tell us, if it is Cocoa (NSView) or Cocoa-Touch (UIView)

Comment: @vikingosegundo I've not done any mac dev but looking at the docs would the OP not have had to use `setAlphaValue:` to not get warnings? But yes you are right bas assumption to make.

Comment: I also didnt do mac development. But I won't answer questions where I have to investigate just to know, what framework OP is using.

Comment: Tagged cocoa-touch, so must be iPhone.

Comment: @jrtc27 I don't think it was originally tagged as that. If you click on the `edited` time below the question you can see all the previous tag/text revisions

Comment: Always forget about that. On iPod Touch, and the revisions don't want to load, so I'll take your word for it!

Comment: Sorry, it is for the iPhone. I started only 2 months ago. Only college programming class experience. Am learning. I will try the UIView recommendation. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question so that it is clearer (I hope). Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @paul.s, thanks for the update. I will look into it. And how do I get my reputation back?

Comment: Check the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation)'s. Basically participation is rewarded. So ask question and make sure you accept the correct answers. Also try answering questions if you can.

Comment: Sorry guys. Was new to developing apple products. All I knew was cocoa touch framework so I didn't even bother to mention it in the question. I only develop on iOS right now, so it's for the cocoa touch framework. Thanks for all the advices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know what the object is in order to know what methods you can call. Use -isKindOfClass: to check that.

Additionally, getters in Cocoa do not start with the word "get." it'd just be -alpha.